# I can't see the result comment on output in Script Editor in Maya MEL

Tags: python, maya, mel

I can't see the result comment on output in Script Editor in Maya MEL and I think It's not have a error when I ran It. I don't know why. I write a Hollow triangle or Hollow Rectangle star " * " Pattern

This is source code

```
global proc print_pattern(string $patternType, int $rows, int $cols)
{
    if ($patternType == "triangle")
    {
        int $i = 0;
        while ($i < $rows)
        {
            int $j = 0;
            while ($j <= $i)
            {
                if ($i == 0 || $i == $rows - 1 || $j == 0 || $j == $i)
                    print("* ");
                else
                    print("  ");
                $j++;
            }
            print("\n");
            $i++;
        }
    }
    else if ($patternType == "rectangle")
    {
        int $i = 0;
        while ($i < $rows)
        {
            int $j = 0;
            while ($j < $cols)
            {
                if ($i == 0 || $i == $rows - 1 || $j == 0 || $j == $cols - 1)
                    print("* ");
                else
                    print("  ");
                $j++;
            }
            print("\n");
            $i++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print("Invalid pattern type. Please choose 'triangle' or 'rectangle'.\n");
    }
}

// Get pattern choice
string $patternChoice = `promptDialog -title "Pattern Type" -message "Enter 'triangle' or 'rectangle' for the pattern type:" -button "OK" -defaultButton "OK" -cancelButton "Cancel" -dismissString "Cancel"`;
if ($patternChoice == "OK")
{
    $patternChoice = `promptDialog -query -text`;
    
    // Print the selected pattern
    if ($patternChoice == "triangle" || $patternChoice == "rectangle")
    {
        int $patternRows = `promptDialog -title "Pattern Rows" -message "Enter the number of rows for the pattern:" -button "OK" -defaultButton "OK" -cancelButton "Cancel" -dismissString "Cancel"`;
        int $patternCols = 0;
        if ($patternRows == "OK")
        {
            $patternRows = `promptDialog -query -text`;
            if ($patternChoice == "rectangle")
            {
                $patternCols = `promptDialog -title "Pattern Columns" -message "Enter the number of columns for the pattern:" -button "OK" -defaultButton "OK" -cancelButton "Cancel" -dismissString "Cancel"`;
                if ($patternCols == "OK")
                {
                    $patternCols = `promptDialog -query -text`;
                }
            }
            print("Star Pattern (", $patternChoice, "):\n");
            print_pattern($patternChoice, $patternRows, $patternCols);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print("Invalid pattern type. Please choose 'triangle' or 'rectangle'.\n");
    }
}
```

I want to know why this happen! Or It's a bug.
.
sadsadasdasdsadasdasdasdasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the result  of pattern choice as: `int $patternRows...` and later you compare it with a string: `if ($patternRows == "OK")` what does not work. The same happens with `$patternCols`. And below you use the `print()` statement in a wrong way.